# Sort new products in product via page

Tags: magento, view, product

When I go now to the product page the old products ar at the top and the arrow pointing downwards but it the arrow have to pointing to the top so that the new products are the first to show.

See printshot: https://gyazo.com/712c7cfa33e237cda3ce8c91045e4916

Best regards,
Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default direction via xml layout.

In your local.xml

```
<layout>
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>asc</string></action>
        <action method="setDefaultOrder"><string>name</string></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>asc</string></action>
        <action method="setDefaultOrder"><string>name</string></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

And this would set your arrow direction in `ascending` order by default on your toolbar. (Also you can set the default order for your sort as you can see on layout above)

Comment: hello K.C. I have add in local.xml but it's not working. see printscreen : https://gyazo.com/19a3e4c590a0a04fc81bbbcd52e6d739

Comment: You can see also http://www.bambinotino.nl/collectie/meisjes the arrow is stil down default.

Comment: Hello K.C. I have update the code but it's still not working. see printscreen. https://gyazo.com/fb5e948221e2a827defbf54ced27b059 See also: http://www.bambinotino.nl/collectie/meisjes The arrow is stil down default so the old products show first.

Comment: K.C. could you please look for me ?

Comment: @MichelVanDeWiel please update your question with your local.xml code part. i can't say seeing your screenshots or site.

Comment: @MichelVanDeWiel you have done it correctly, as copying from your part also works perfectly on mine. what i can see is, your sorter doesn't have a default class `sort-by-switcher sort-by-switcher--asc` you might be using other theme than default and might be theme issue probably. (i tested on default magento theme)